# ¿Se deberían sacar las etiquetas de los títulos de las preguntas en ediciones?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas

Mientras revisando ediciones veo mucho que la gente borran palabras claves del título de la pregunta porque el contexto ya sería claro desde la etiqueta.

Por ejemplo:

**¿Como puedo agregar iconos al menubar en netbeans?**

Se cambia a

**¿Como puedo agregar iconos al menubar?**

Argumentando que NetBeans ya sería incluido como etiqueta.

Yo dudo que eso mejora la experiencia de usuario en SOes, tal cual como no creo que este "redundancia" presenta un problema, incluso prefería títulos que dan un contexto lo más preciso que posible.

Para sacar una buena idea como reaccionar con este tipo de ediciones, me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como la presencia/ausencia de la palabra clave impacta resultados en la búsqueda (sin filtrar por etiqueta), algo que probablemente depende como se construye la metadata de las preguntas.

¿El contexto puede quedarse, o es mejor de sacar todo lo que se puede colocar como etiqueta?

Comment: Existe una pregunta similar en Meta SE: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/182862). La respuesta corta es: "**it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles**". Traducido: "**es completamente innecesario forzar las etiquetas en los títulos de tus preguntas**".

Comment: Entiendo, no es necesario, y no estaba hablando de **forzarlo**, lo que se agregue el primer tag ya esta bien, pero tampoco veo la necesidad de sacar más contexto si la pregunta sigue siendo buen español. Preguntando más concreto, piensas que hay que forzarlos **fuera**?

Comment: Solo agregaría alguna info de la etiqueta en el título si fuese estrictamente necesario. Títulos como "Error Java", "Problema con aspx", "Duda de Android Studio", "Qué hago mal .Net" o "Jquery auto completado", "Oracle obtener maximo", no me parecen bien en absoluto porque la etiqueta ya delimita esto. Además, cuando aparece la notificación, te sale como <etiqueta> - <titulo de pregunta>

Comment: Hasta donde se, cuando haces una búsqueda en Google la etiqueta principal aparece justo antes del titulo de la pregunta, seguido por un guion (dash), Ej: [php - Get all variables sent with POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207488/get-all-variables-sent-with-post)... Asi que parecería innecesario (al menos, con fines de la búsqueda) [Tocar aqui](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHZL_esAR709AR709&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=php+-+Get+all+variables+sent+with+POST%3F)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza concuerdo que los ejemplos de preguntas que listaste son pesimos, pero ya antes de incorporar el tag. "Que hago mál" es algo que es ridiculo en el sentido que la mayoría de las personas en SO hicíeron algo "mál", si no no tuvieron que preguntar que podrían hacer mejor. Sin embargo el hombre es visual, y hay muchos lugares en que se muestran preguntas sin las etiquetas a la vista, y a mi en el chat por ejemplo ayuda bastante de tener todo el contexto a la vista cuando entran nuevas preguntas.

Comment: Para eso existen las ediciones libres por parte de los usuarios con mayor reputación. Para que podamos editar esas cosas que no brindan la calidad del sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya por la simple razón que en las alertas en desktop y chat solamente se muestra el título de las preguntas y no todas las etiquetas asociadas prefería dejar los títulos lo más completo que posible, dejando las etiquetas como herramientas de filtrar.

Si se necesita un ejemplo por que:

Si veo una pregunta **"¿Como puedo sumar dos variables tipo Float?"** en el chat, no lo voy a pescar, hay millones de usuarios que pueden responder a eso.

Sin embargo si veo: **"¿Como puedo sumar dos variables tipo Float en brainfuck/malbolge/piet?"** la pregunta empieza ser sumamente interesante.

Encontré una opinión que podría ser interesante en el asunto para formarse una opinión si es necesario de cometer un genocidio que todas las palabras en un titulo que suceden ser etiquetas también:

> two rules: 1) think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally and 2) if the most important tag on the question doesn't work in the title at all, it implies your tagging system is fundamentally broken. See [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles) – Jeff Atwood♦ Feb 5 '11 at 4:45

traducción:

> dos reglas: 1) pienso que esta bien duplicar etiquetas en el titulo, pero solamente si se juntan al titulo organicamente y conversacionalmente y 2) si la etiqueta más importante no funciona nada en el titulo, implica que algo esta fundamentalmente mal con el sistema de etiquetar. - Jeff Atwood

Comment: Si viese una pregunta con el segundo título, ya mi mente estaría con un 50% de voto a cierre porque me late a que no ha intentado nada o su intento es muy básico y el OP no se ha dignado a buscar en internet cómo hacerlo y espera que alguien investigue por él/ella, codifique por él/ella, y demás. Sin embargo, esta es mi idea solamente, no la del sitio en general.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza en este caso me parece que fueron casos demostrativos, aún así, se debería revisar la pregunta para saber si cae en la clasificación que comentas.

Comment: @Flxtr así es, pero mi mente ya se inclina a un 50% basado en la cantidad de preguntas que he visto desde el 2011 en SOen y en las que he visto en SOes desde diciembre de 2015. Pero ese es otro punto que se sale del foco de la pregunta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no sé si conoces malbolge, pero ya definir un Float es un desafío. Brainfuck no tanto, pero tampoco pan comido. Piet es - bueno - colorado. Si me encuantras un enlace en el internet donde sale explicado en forma simple como implementar operaciónes con Float en malbolge, te admiro.

Comment: Es simple: rtfm.

Comment: Buena Suerte. Ni siquiera si existiera un fm sería fácil.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que planteaste en la pregunta @Stefan, así como la visión general de mantenerlas cuando son orgánicas, pero tengo una pequeña objeción con tu primer planteo en esta respuesta: creo que, que no aparezcan en alertas y chat, es un *problema xy*... es decir, si el problema fuese que no se ven ahí, corrijamos ***eso*** (ya sea con una solicitud o con un user script).

Comment: @Mariano el ejemplo con el feed en el chat es solamente un lugar en que aparece el titulo de la pregunta pero no las etiquetas. Cosa de venta - lo que el cliente no ve, no lo compra. Yo creo que lo que dijo JA aquí tiene mucho sentido. Yo veo las etiquetas como herramientas de busqueda y organisación, pero no deberían remplazar una pregunta completa con el contexto dado. El "feel" de la pregunta también anima a responder.

Comment: @Stefan voté +1 a la rta de JoseAntonio, y estoy de acuerdo con mantener las del tipo `cómo x en tag` y eliminar en el tipo `cómo x - [tag]`... Mi comentario apuntaba exclusivamente a que está bien cubrir la "*Cosa de venta*", pero creo que la solución no sería atacando los títulos, sino atacando el problema de fondo: mostrar las etiquetas en todas las ocurrencias dentro de la interfaz donde deberían aparecer.

Comment: También :) Eso soporto.

Answer (score 5):

Muy en lo personal, periferia que se queden si las han puesto, es muy normal para un usuario nuevo el no usar las etiquetas del todo correctas, a mi me paso y no creo que haya alguien a quien no le pudo haber pasado, y haciendo referencia a la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1364/24364) que dio [@Stefan Nolde](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/26822/stefan-nolde), no es lo mismo:

**¿Cómo puedo mostrar un alert en JavaScript?**

**¿Cómo puedo mostrar un alert en JQuery?**

**¿Cómo puedo mostrar un alert en AngularJS?**

En las etiquetas generales del la pregunta puede ir, y de manera muy acertada, la etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) ya que las 3 preguntas hablan de esto en mayor o menor media, mientras que el especificar un poco mas, a mi que se poco de *Angular* no entraría a responder la pregunta, pero si abriría la revisar la primera o la segunda ya que tengo conocimientos del mismo.

Si bien las etiquetas sirven para hacer esta diferencia, no creo que este de mas el poner en el título de la pregunta la etiqueta

Comment: En https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging se menciona que se debe evitar etiquetas en los títulos. Entre los ejemplos de las cosas a evitar está poner `en [etiqueta]` (Siendo estrictos dice `in` en lugar de `en` pero es un problema de traducción)

Answer (score 0):

*Los ejemplos que colocaste en tu pregunta* me parecen correctos, pero si consideras que los títulos pueden tener una mejor redacción, puedes intentarlo.

---

Sin embargo, he encontrado algunas preguntas que en sus títulos colocan las etiquetas; en esos casos estoy de acuerdo en editar los títulos y colocar las etiquetas correspondientes *(si no las tiene)*:

- [Acceder a datos JSON (PHP, AJAX)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/46219/78)
- ¿Cómo guardo este valor en base de datos [C#]? * *es un ejemplo.*

Answer (score -1):

**Se debe respetar el criterio original del autor.**

Hay quien piensa que con el sistema de tags de SO es suficiente. [Respuesta a : Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Hay quien piensa que los títulos debieran valerse por sí mismos, sin depender de tags. [Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags)

Ambos estilos son aceptables en la política del sitio.

Lo que es inaceptable es editar una pregunta para cambiar de un estilo que no te gusta a uno que sí te gusta. Hay que respetar al autor de la pregunta. Si la edición de una pregunta quita palabras tipo tag del título, o si añade palabras tipo tag al título, repórtalo para atención de moderador.

Comment: La pregunta fue atcualizada, es referente a las ediciones, no a las creaciones

Comment: Mi respuesta es referente a las ediciones. El criterio del autor es lo que importa con respecto a si se deberían sacar las etiquetas de los títulos de las preguntas en las ediciones. Se debe respetar el criterio original del autor en esta cuestión.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que una edición no puede quedar a criterio del autor, como lo comentas en la primer línea, en ese caso debería decir, *Queda a criterio del editor*

Comment: Ciertamente cuando editas es muy posible que no tengas al autor a mano para pedirle su criterio. Lo que quiero decir es que se debe respetar el criterio original del autor al hacer ediciones. Tanto poner como no poner etiquetas en el título es aceptable, cambiarlo solo mejora o empeora una pregunta desde un punto de vista subjetivo. Es por tanto una edición contraria a "Las ediciones deben ser sustanciales y dejar la publicación mejor de como se encontró." como indica el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Espero que mi edición te resulte más clara.

Comment: A eso me referí cuando dije en alguna parte que uno se debería limitar a lo necesario en ediciones, como formato, ortografía (ojala no en bloques de código) etc. Aparte de eso hay que saber lo que uno hace, reformateo el código de python puede cambiar drasticamente la posibilidad de encontrar un error. Si el origina no es salvable sin quedar reconocible para el autor como su pregunta, sería mejor de dejar un comentario pidiendo rehecho y votar para cierre.